# How to see all matching ranges with git blame?

Tags: git, blame

I can output first range matching regex with a command:

```
git blame -L'/start_regex/','/end_regex/' file
```

But how to output all next ranges matching this regex in the same file?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, `git blame -L'/start_regex/','/end_regex/'` will only return the first match.

You now can (git 1.8.5 December 2013) specify **multiple ranges**, since [commit 58dbfa2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/58dbfa2e59a11b3dd060d69788af4c3decc7ee22) and Eric Sunshine's sunshine work.

So you *could* try (in git 1.8.5, not tested)

```
git blame -L'/start_regex/','/end_regex/' -L'/start_regex/','/end_regex/' file
```

That would check if you can get two different matches, but that doesn't scale well.

That means it could be a good idea for a patch to [`builtin/blame.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/blame.c).

Comment: Wow, 2000+ lines of C code... But, may be, I will try to propose the patch for the following way: `-L start_regex,end_regex[,num_of_matches]` - if number of matches is not specified, then output all matches. But I don't know how should one handle overlapping ranges...